# How to make an html element appear and disappear again and again with Js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on my portfolio and i'd like to add an animated arrow to invite the user to scroll down. The arrow would be made of 2 blocks + the arrow and I'd like to animate them such as this:
The first element appear, then the 2nd one (while the first one fade out), then the 3rd one (while the 1st appear again and the 2nd one fade out).
I've tried many scripts like this one (which is made for 2 elements only) :

```
function test() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 11; i = i + 1) {
            if (i % 2 !== 0) {
                document.getElementById('square1').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById('square2').style.visibility = 'hidden';

            } else {
                document.getElementById('square1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('square2').style.visibility = 'visible';
            };
        };
    }
```

This only makes the element visible in browser, I was thinking that the square were 'blinkink' too fast to be noticed due to the loop beeing computed real quick so I tried to add a sleep function but it didnt work either.

Could anyone please help me with this ? As a bonus question, i'm fine with the function running when website loads but it would be even better if the animation could start when the user scroll down to a defined part of the website!

P.S: I'm not using jQuery, i want to dig in Js before using frameworks.

Thanks ! And sorry for my english :)

Edit: I finally have a working function for animating 3 elements. I struggled a bit but in the end, could make it thanks to your help guys so thanks for the example and links you provided
Here is the code if it's of interest for anyone, I think it could need some refactoring but i'm happy with it anyway:

```
    function appear() {
        alert(container[test]);
        document.getElementById(container[test]).style.visibility = 'visible';
        if(test === 0) {
          document.getElementById(container[test + 1]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.getElementById(container[test + 2]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
          test++
        } else if(test === 1) {
          document.getElementById(container[test - 1]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.getElementById(container[test + 1]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
          test++
        } else {
          document.getElementById(container[test - 1]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.getElementById(container[test - 2]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
          test = 0;
        }

    }

    function animate() {
        var interval = setInterval(appear, 1000);
    }

    var test = 0;
    var sq1 = 'square1';
    var sq2 = 'square2';
    var arrow = 'arrow';
    var container = [sq1, sq2, arrow];

    alert('test' + container);

    animate();
```

Comment: javascript process your code so fast and you will not see any result.you need to add delay to make it work

Comment: Yes, that's why i tried adding a sleep function, any hints about where i could find a solution to add a working delay/sleep function ?

Comment: you need to setInterval, not sleep function

please see this doc http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Thank your for the link, this could be what i need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using setInterval method:-

```
var interval=500,i=0;
setInterval(function(){
  i++;
   if (i % 2 !== 0) {
     document.getElementById('square1').style.visibility = 'visible';
     document.getElementById('square2').style.visibility = 'hidden';

   } else {
     document.getElementById('square1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
     document.getElementById('square2').style.visibility = 'visible';
   }
},interval);
```

if you want it to go active after it reached a point on the page use an if construct to verify the scrollTop of the page:-

```
if(document.body.scrollTop>=500){
  ...
  //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you and Alongkorn for letting me know about setInterval()

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this would best be address with an animated image or CSS animations rather than a series of elements animated with JavaScript. So I'll include a CSS example, but also the JavaScript example you asked for.

Here's the CSS example, [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) on CSS Tricks discusses how CSS animations work (I'm not expert); note we animate `opacity` rather than `visibility`, and CSS gives us a nice easing effect (there are others):

```css
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {opacity: 1}
  50% {opacity: 0}
}
.blocks {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
.block1 {
  animation: pulse 2.4s ease 0s infinite;
}
.block2 {
  animation: pulse 2.4s ease 0.8s infinite;
}
.block3 {
  animation: pulse 2.4s ease 1.6s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks block1"></div>
<div class="blocks block2"></div>
<div class="blocks block3"></div>
```

But if you want to use elements animated with JavaScript: The issue with the code you've posted is that it never yields back to the browser to allow it to update the display. So instead of a loop, you'd use `setTimeout` to change the visibility of the elements (see comments):

```js
// Get the blocks
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".blocks");

// Keep track of which block we're currently showing
var index = -1;

// Start
cycle();
function cycle() {
  // Get the current block if any
  var block = index >= 0 && blocks[index];
  if (block) {
    // Hide it again
    block.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  
  // Move to the next block, wrapping around when we get to the end
  index = (index + 1) % blocks.length;
  
  // Show it
  block = blocks[index];
  block.style.visibility = "visible";
  
  // Call this function again in 800ms
  setTimeout(cycle, 800);
}
```

```css
.blocks {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks block1"></div>
<div class="blocks block2"></div>
<div class="blocks block3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and providing 2 different solutions, very helpful

Comment: Works fine with CSS animation, thanks a lot ! I'll also try the Js script.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the toggle() function. Which changes the css property between hidden and visible. Alternatively you could use the hide() and show() functions as well. Further more to solve your scroll property you could have do something like this:

```
var y = $('.selector').scrollTop(); //gives you the vertical scroll position
if(y%30 == 0) {
$('.arrowOne').toggle();
$('.arrowTwo').toggle();
}
```

This will toggle the arrows for every scroll change of 30.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i will try re write the function using toggle() as it seems more appropriate.

Comment: *"I'm not using jQuery, i want to dig in Js before using frameworks"*

Comment: Is there any problem with this ? Do you think i should use JQuery as a way to learn Js ?

Comment: I apologize I didn't see the no JQuery part. I learnt Js and JQuery together. But that's a personal choice.

Comment: No problem Alan, i was reacting to what T.J Crowder said. I know jQuery is very useful and efficient but 'i d like to be able to write my own scripts in a first place before using existing scripts.